# Using Userform to run a macro

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I did up a Userform and a macro. My problem is I do not know how to combine them together. The Userform should come out and allow the user to type in the relevant data needed on the click of the command  button. Thereafter, it will run the macro I have written. How do i do it?

Macro for userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

  Sub Okay_Click()
        Dim ID1 As String, ID2 As String

        ID1 = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value


        If Len(ID1 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box A is empty"

            Exit Sub
        End If

        ID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value
        If Len(ID2 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box B is empty"
            Else


            Exit Sub
        End If
UserForm3.Hide



End Sub




Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ID1 As String

    ID1 = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim ID2 As String

    ID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Macro written:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim SO As String
Dim Balance As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim ID1 As String
Dim ID2 As String


UserForm3.Show


Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NZ Generic Stock")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock (Data)")
SO = Source.Range("A3")
Balance = Source.Range("I16")

Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(2 + i, 4)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 2 of column 4
    If Target.Cells(2 + i, 4) = SO Then
        ItsAMatch = True
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 5) = Balance ' This will overwrite your "Balance" value if the name was already in the column
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
' This will write new records if the SO hasn't been already found
If ItsAMatch = False Then
    Target.Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = SO
    Target.Cells(1, 5).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = Balance
End If

Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing




End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove Userform3.hide in UserForm_Click()

Instead of putting macro in Command1_Click() Just put Userform3.hide

Put in new macro inside the module and try to execute the Macro
Like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

  Sub Okay_Click()
        Dim ID1 As String, ID2 As String

        ID1 = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value


        If Len(ID1 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box A is empty"

            Exit Sub
        End If

        ID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value
        If Len(ID2 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box B is empty"
            Else


            Exit Sub
        End If
End Sub




Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ID1 As String

    ID1 = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim ID2 As String

    ID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value
End Sub



Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm3.Hide

End Sub
```

Macro Like this

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim SO As String
Dim Balance As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim ID1 As String
Dim ID2 As String


UserForm3.Show


Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NZ Generic Stock")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock (Data)")
SO = Source.Range("A3")
Balance = Source.Range("I16")

Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(2 + i, 4)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 2 of column 4
    If Target.Cells(2 + i, 4) = SO Then
        ItsAMatch = True
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 5) = Balance ' This will overwrite your "Balance" value if the name was already in the column
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
' This will write new records if the SO hasn't been already found
If ItsAMatch = False Then
    Target.Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = SO
    Target.Cells(1, 5).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = Balance
End If

Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing




End Sub
```

Comment: so the userform will link to the mymacro?

Comment: I don't get it, should i be putting everything into a module or I can leave them separate?

Comment: I click ok and it will not go to the macro. the userform stays there too

Comment: yes i did, is this sub together with the userform or seperate?

Comment: Right click CommandButton1 and select View Code there you need to put UserForm3.Hide

Comment: i did it,so i should have 3 areas right? one is the command button, one is the userform, and one is at the module?

Comment: i can use the name Mymacro? anywhere i need to change?

Comment: You can use any name you can